# Upcasting Generics

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Ok, I know this is impossible, but I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to get around this.

```
List<int> numberList = new List<int>();

List<object> objectList = (List<object>)numberList;
```

This generates the following error:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List{int}' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List{object}'

This is a simple example, but here is my real problem.  I have a method that dynamically generates an `IQueryable{IGrouping{TKey, TElement}}` instance.  However, since in my case `TKey` is dynamically generated, I can only return an `IQueryable` to the caller.

I want to be able to return an `IQueryable{IGrouping{dynamic, TElement}}` to the caller.  However, the compiler complains because just like in my first example, its casting `TKey` as an object (for `dynamic`), and won't let me cast it that way.  Is there any way around that?

Update:

Here is a closer example of what I'm trying to solve:

```
List<int> testList = new List<int>();

var qry = new EnumerableQuery<int>( testList );

var objectQry = (IQueryable<object>)qry;
```

While this example doesn't produce a compile-time error, is does produce a casting exception when you try to run it.  For some reason, even though `IQuerable` is covariant (thanks Servy for your comments on that), once I introduce an implementing class such as `EnumerableQuery`, it fails.

Comment: If its impossible, what makes you think we can do it ;)

Comment: well, as developers and problem solvers, we usually don't accept no as an answer. We look for new ways of solving things, hence my question.

Comment: I know, clearly you didn't catch the wink in my smile. I am planning on upvoting as soon as the limits reset, I think this is a pretty interesting question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct a copy of each new dictionary, because dictionaries as well as lists are not covariant with respect to any of their generic arguments.

(The keys are also provided in output through the `Keys` property, and the sequence of pairs itself, so even `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` cannot be covariant with respect to `TKey`.)

You can use `Select` to map each object to a new object:

```
List<Dictionary<int, string>> listOfDicts = new List<Dictionary<int, string>>();
List<Dictionary<object, string>> newList = listOfDicts.Select(dic =>
        dic.ToDictionary(pair => (object)pair.Key, pair => pair.Value))
    .ToList();
```

`IQueryable<T>` on the other hand *is* covariant, as is `IGrouping`, so you can cast interfaces of those types up:

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<dynamic, int>> query = null;
IQueryable<IGrouping<object, int>> otherQuery = query;
```

That compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and it works as you have written it, but after some more testing, it still doesn't solve my problem... I'll edit my example to demonstrate.

Comment: @NathanA Covariance can only be applied to reference types, not to value types.  `int` is a value type.

Comment: I guess it helps to mention that covariance didn't exist in 3.5, hence some of my confusion.  I'm writing a library for both 3.5 and 4.0, and the unit test I was testing was running the 3.5 build...Good to know.  And thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
List<int> numberList = new List<int>();
List<object> objectList = numberList.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

[`Enumerable.Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type.

Comment: While this answer does work for my simple example, it does not work for my IGrouping case. Both LINQ to objects and LINQ to Entities produces errors when attempting to execute the cast.